# c encrypt decrypt not working as expected

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement encode and decode of string based on this page

http://www.thecrazyprogrammer.com/2016/11/caesar-cipher-c-c-encryption-decryption.html

And here is the code,

```
string encryptString(string message){

    int i, key=95828205;
    char ch;
    for(i = 0; message[i] != '\0'; ++i){
            ch = message[i];

            if(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z'){
                ch = ch + key;

                if(ch > 'z'){
                    ch = ch - 'z' + 'a' - 1;
                }

                message[i] = ch;
            }
            else if(ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z'){
                ch = ch + key;

                if(ch > 'Z'){
                    ch = ch - 'Z' + 'A' - 1;
                }

                message[i] = ch;
            }
        }
      printf("Encrypted message: %s", message);
      return message;
}

string  decryptString(string message){

     int i, key=95828205;
     char ch;
    for(i = 0; message[i] != '\0'; ++i){
            ch = message[i];

            if(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z'){
                ch = ch - key;

                if(ch < 'a'){
                    ch = ch + 'z' - 'a' + 1;
                }

                message[i] = ch;
            }
            else if(ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z'){
                ch = ch - key;

                if(ch < 'A'){
                    ch = ch + 'Z' - 'A' + 1;
                }

                message[i] = ch;
            }
        }

     printf("Decrypted message: %s", message);
     return message;
}
```

And called the function like,

```
string msg="test.com",msg1,msg2;
msg1 = encryptString(msg);
msg2 = decryptString(msg1);
```

But I am getting some random character while decrypt the data back

Comment: `printf("Encrypted message: %s", message);`with message as std::string?

Answer (score 3):

You have defined

```
key=95828205;
```

Then you add it to character from an array and store it to array

```
if(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z'){
     ch = ch + key;
     message[i] = ch;
     ...
```

And it means that character has overflowed and there is some random number.

Then if you try to check (in encrypt)

```
 if(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z'){
      ch = ch - key;
```

There isn't high change that the value will be in that interval.

---

**TO DO**

You should swap these lines (first get real letter and then compare it)

```
 ch = ch - key;
 if(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z'){
      ...
```

And use `key` which wont cause `char` overflow (e.g. 5)

---

**EDIT**

Test after changes

**Input**

```
Message: test
Key:     5
```

**Output from encrypt**

```
yjxy
```

**Output from decrypt**

```
test
```

Answer (score 1):

There are only 127 valid ascii characters (7-bits). If you add more than that and convert back to 'char' you will get incorrect results.

You can test this with simple code

```
int main()
{
  char c = 'u';
  char n = c+10;
  printf("0x%x 0x%x\n",c,n);
  return 0;
}
```

Set the value of 'c' beyond letter u and you will get incorrect results. Example c = 'v' gives :

```
kmukadam@4W28N62: ./a.out
0x76 0xffffff80
```

Comment: Um, actually, ASCII has 128 characters.